# Vue.js + Creating async contructor Class and accessing the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am a newbie and need help. I have created a class and i want to initialize my data property 'Filters' on created function with the value returned from the constructor of the class 'Filters'
However as i am calling an async webapi it does not return anything into my property. How can i achieve this using class

```
<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
  Filters : [];
};
},
methods: {},
created () {
   this.Filters = new Filters(); // returns promise pending
}
};
```

```
class Filters
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.filters = this.loadFilters();
    }

    async loadFilters ()
    {
        const query = `?$select=*&$filter=_new_table_value eq ${window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace(/[{}]/g, "")}&$orderby=ice_name asc`;
        var result = await window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords('ice_filterstable', query);
        console.log(result); // this does return values 
        return result;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't assign an async operation on the class constructor, it would be better to use `loadFilters` async function directly.

```
class Filters
{
constructor() {}

async loadFilters ()
{
    const query = `?$select=*&$filter=_new_table_value eq ${window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace(/[{}]/g, "")}&$orderby=ice_name asc`;
    var result = await window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords('ice_filterstable', query);
    console.log(result); // this does return values 
    return result;
}
}
```

And then in the `created` lifecycle, you can execute the `loadFilters` function.

```
async created () {
    const filters = new Filters(); // returns promise pending
    this.Filters = await filters.loadFilters()
}
```